# Request XML file using vb.net application

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to request a XML file Using VB.net and load it in my application.

I have been able to use a JavaScript in the past which uses XMLHttpRequest but now I am trying to create a application that will allow me to request a XML file and parse it.

In the past I have used the following JavaScript code to request and show the reply in a textarea:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="send_command()">GET</button>

<textarea id="test1" name="test1" cols="90" rows="30">
XML file will be displayed here
</textarea><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function send_command()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("test1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        var url = "http://192.168.0.50/my_xml_file.xml";

        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false,"admin","admin");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But now I am trying to do the same thing but using VB.net (2012) as a windows Application.

After doing a quick Google on this, I have found the following code:

```
' Create a WebRequest to the remote site
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.50/my_xml_file.xml")

' NB! Use the following line ONLY if the website is protected
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")

' Call the remote site, and parse the data in a response object
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

' Check if the response is OK (status code 200)
If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then

    ' Parse the contents from the response to a stream object
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Create a reader for the stream object
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
    ' Read from the stream object using the reader, put the contents in a string
    Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Create a new, empty XML document
    Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

    ' Load the contents into the XML document
    document.LoadXml(contents)

    ' Now you have a XmlDocument object that contains the XML from the remote site, you can
    ' use the objects and methods in the System.Xml namespace to read the document

Else
    ' If the call to the remote site fails, you'll have to handle this. There can be many reasons, ie. the 
    ' remote site does not respond (code 404) or your username and password were incorrect (code 401)
    '
    ' See the codes in the System.Net.HttpStatusCode enumerator 

    Throw New Exception("Could not retrieve document from the URL, response code: " & response.StatusCode)

End If
```

However when I run the code above in VB.net I get an error:

[image]

I can't seem to work out why this error is happening.

Does anyone know what the error above means or better still is the VB.net code above going to do what I am trying to do?

(My XML file requires a username and password to view the XML)

Comment: I have no idea about vb.net, but the error sounds like an issue with line endings. It seems to expect CRLF, but is finding only LF. Are you sure that the file has Windows (CRLF) line endings and not *nix (LF)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to put this into your web.config file:

```
<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>
</settings>
</system.net>
```

and see if that gets around the error for you.

Comment: where do I find the web.config file? I can only find the App.config file.

Comment: You should be able to add it to app.config too.

Comment: Thanks for that, but now I am getting a error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (and the user/pass I am using it correct)